# MongoDB $lookup on array of documents containing object id

Tags: mongodb

I want to make aggregation pipeline in MongoDB v4.4.

I have two collections.

1. `users` collection

   ```
   [
     { _id: "user1", username: "john" },
     { _id: "user2", username: "bob" },
   ]
   ```
2. `articles` collection

   ```
   [
     {
       _id: "article1",
       view_history: [
         { user: "user1", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
         { user: "user2", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
         { user: "user1", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
       ]
     }
   ]
   ```

My desired result after running aggregation on `articles` collection is:

```
[
  {
    _id: "article1",
    view_history: [
      { user: "john", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
      { user: "bob", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
      { user: "john", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
    ]
  }
]
```

So `user` fields on each history item in `view_history` are substituted with the user's `username`.

I tried many answers on SO, but can't find any solution for my situation.
Here's what I got so far:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "view_history.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "output",
    }
  }
])
```

Which yields:

```
[
  {
    _id: "article1",
    view_history: [
      { user: "user1", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
      { user: "user2", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
      { user: "user1", viewed_at: ISODate("...") },
    ],
    output: [
      { _id: "user1", username: "john" },
      { _id: "user2", username: "bob" },
    ]
  }
]
```

(There's only one `user1` in `output`, and `viewed_at` not included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `view_history` array
- `$lookup` with `users` collection
- get first element from `view_history.user.username` because it will return array using `$arrayElemAt`
- `$group` by `_id` and re-construct `view_history` array

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$view_history" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "view_history.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "view_history.user"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "view_history.user": {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$view_history.user.username", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      view_history: {
        $push: "$view_history"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9kPxqPGs4l8)

---

Second approach:

- `$lookup` with `users` collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `view_history` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `output` array and match `user` field
- `$let` declare variable `u` for above filter, `in` to get first element from filtered result using `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "view_history.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "output"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      view_history: {
        $map: {
          input: "$view_history",
          as: "v",
          in: {
            user: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  u: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$output",
                      cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$v.user"] }
                    }
                  }
                },
                in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$u.username", 0] }
              }
            },
            viewed_at: "$$v.viewed_at"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZm2ARXFJTc)

Comment: The first approach works fine, but there was a problem that result documents don't contain original article's fields other than `view_history`. I fixed it by adding `$replaceRoot` stage at the last. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I'm using MongoDB 4.4, and I heard that there's new syntax in `$lookup` stage, which uses `let`, `pipeline` instead of `localField`, `foreignField`. I saw it gets rid of usage of `$unwind`, but I wonder if this will be applied to my situation.

Comment: i don't think new syntax lookup with pipeline is useful for your example, because the articles collection already have `view_history` array field and inside lookup pipeline you have to do same process that i have did in my second approach.